# Authentication for Docker private Registry v2

Tags: docker-registry

I am Trying to setup docker-distribution (formally Docker registry v2) with SSO authentication, can you please let me know the possible solution

Comment: no research done.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout project [Portus](http://port.us.org/). You can use LDAP authentication or registration-based login.

If you are searching for something more lightweight, checkout this [article](http://container-solutions.com/running-secured-docker-registry-2-0/) allowing to use simple htpasswd file for authentication.